# Changing an array of tags' attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of objects (data)

```
data[0].image = image1.jpg;
data[0].name = "some name";

data[1].image = image2.jpg;
data[1].name = "some name";

data[2].image = image3.jpg;
data[2].name = "some name";

data[3].image = image4.jpg;
data[3].name = "some name";
```

I also have a group of  tags nested in a ul.

```
<ul class='swapme'>
  <li><img class="swapme" src="a.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img class="swapme" src="b.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img class="swapme" src="c.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img class="swapme" src="d.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
```

I know I can grab the img tags with

```
$('ul.swapme').children('img.swapme')
```

I know I can swap out each images src attribute with

```
$('img.swapme').attr('src', data[0].image)
```

My question is, what is the right way to swap out the src attribute with the corresponding data object. ie, a.jpg becomes image1.jpg. . . ect. . .

If I use loops it looks ugly and clumsy, can anyone provide a better way / the right way to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an `$.each()` loop and utilize the `index`:

```
var data = [
    {'image':'image1.jpg', 'name':'some name'},
    {'image':'image2.jpg', 'name':'some name'},
    {'image':'image3.jpg', 'name':'some name'},
    {'image':'image4.jpg', 'name':'some name'},
];

$('ul.swapme').find('img.swapme').each(function (index, value) {
    $(value).attr('src', data[index].image);
});
```

Note that I changed `$('ul.swapme').children('img.swapme')` to `$('ul.swapme').find('img.swapme')` as the image tags are not direct descendants of the unordered list tag.

Here is a jsfiddle of this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/Bycse/

Answer (score 2):

Simply use [jQuery's each method](http://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
$('ul.swapme img.swapme').each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr('src', data[i].image);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to loop, though I don't think it's all that ugly:

```
$.each(data,function(index){
    $("img.swapme").eq(index).attr("src",this.image);
});
```

Comment: Fair enough.  Looping the other way would be more efficient.